# How to use Data.Map ! Operator?

Tags: haskell

I have the following anti-pattern in my code:

```
existsFunc :: Maybe Item -> Item
```

This is part of a larger piece of code that checks if a name is in a Dictionary:

```
genFunc :: InputType -> Item
genFunc input = existsFunc(Data.Map.lookup input (myDictionary))
  
existsFunc :: Maybe Item -> Item
existsFunc (Just x) = x
existsFunc Nothing = error "input missing from dictionary"
```

I would like to replace the above anti-pattern with with [! Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html) operator, but am having trouble understanding the syntax. How can the ! be applied?

```
genFunc :: InputType -> Item
genFunc input = ! Data.Map.lookup input (myDictionary) Error: element not in the map
genFunc input = Data.Map.lookup input (myDictionary)
```

edit:

I also thought that it could be applied in the following way:

```
genFunc :: InputType -> Item
genFunc input = Data.Map.lookup input (myDictionary) ! input Error: element not in the map
genFunc input = Data.Map.lookup input (myDictionary)
```

Comment: The typical solution is that `genFunc` would return a `Maybe Item` and you would not use `(!)` (which has the same problem as `existsFunc`), but instead *only* use `lookup`. The `Nothing` case of the `Maybe` is "handled" later in the spot where you are able to handle it properly.

Comment: For completeness, it's worth mentioning that `m ! v` is essentially the same as your `existsFunc (Data.Map.lookup v m)`. As I said, though, `(!)` has the same problem as `existsFunc` (and, therefore, is *also* an anti-pattern for the same reason)

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
genFunc input = myDictionary Data.Map.! input
```

Usually people give a short name like `M` to the `Data.Map` module, using an import like:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
```

Then this shorter version is right:

```
genFunc input = myDictionary M.! input
```

Probably not even worth naming this function. Just use `M.!` inline wherever you were gonna use `genFunc`.

Keep in mind that `!` is exactly as much an antipattern as your `existsFunc`. So don't think you're fixing that here -- a real fix involves handling `Nothing` from `lookup` for real. Each application's needs here vary; sometimes using a default value is correct, sometimes raising an error in some containing monad is correct, sometimes propagating the `Maybe` into the caller's return type is correct, ...and half a dozen other responses exist out there, I'm sure.